# Black window when running Postman on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, electron, postman

When running Postman on Windows 7

This is the screen that I can see:

[image]

In what way can I debug why this is happening? And what could be the fix for this?

Comment: How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is this an actual question?

Comment: What version of Postman are you using? If it's pretty outdated you could try to install the latest release.

Answer (score 2):

Clean up the indexDb folder and backup file, in those folders: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Postman
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Postman

They are getting too big with time and it makes Postman crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I solved it:

- Go to *Control Panel -> System -> System Properties -> Advanced ->
  Environment Variables*
- Click *New*
- Enter variable `( POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU )` and value `(true)`
- Press *OK*

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpakS_yy1LE

Comment: Unfortunatelly the video does not exist anymore and adding the environment variable didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Is this for the latest version of Postman? You could try:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/installation_and_updates#troubleshooting-postman-updates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Also changing between requests in postman was lagging.
I solved it by logging out and logging in again (version 6.5.3/windows 10).
After about a minute after I logged in again, it performed normally again.